# submit button doesnot lead back to index in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am new to Ruby on rails and i was trying to figure out where my code is failing. I created an Articles table so when i go to articles/new where if have the view to create article after i click on submit button it doesnot go to /articles but in terminal, it shows that a post request was made.

I have created a table articles and Model Article along with article_controller class
also in the routes i have added  resources :articles

But when i visit to articles/new and create a new article using the form i can see the create fn in the controller is called due to the POST request on article_path (/articles/) (because i tried to save the article into db and it did got saved) but when i try to display the article details using `render plain: @articles.inspect` nothing happens and it remains on /articles/new even after hitting the submit button (even if the create fn in empty it stays on that page). Please Help!

Controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
    def index
        @articles = Article.all()
    end
    def new

    end
    def create
        render plain: @article.inspect
    end
end
```

Model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 50}
    validates :description, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10, maximum: 100}
end
```

New Form

```
<h1>Create an Article <h1>
<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, method: :post, local: true do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :description %><br/>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Index Page

```
<h1>Showing All Articles</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @articles.each do |article|%>
            <tr>
                <td><%= article.title%></td>
                <td><%= article.description%></td>
                <td>PlaceHolder</td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to replicate your issue completely however I think you are pursuing a wrong approach therefore I am posting an answer.

For the scenario where the `create` action is empty it is the expected behaviour that the browser will stay on the `articles/new` page because it did not get no `render` nor `redirect` response so it has nothing to do.

For the scenario where `create` renders `render plain: @article.inspect` I expected it to render empty page with text "nil" and it did. This is because `@article` is never initialized and instance variables don't raise an undefined variable error but instead return `nil`. So I was not able to replicate your exact behaviour (stay on the page) and you may want to inspect the response in the browser if you want to spend some more time with that.

However as a beginner you should not create your Model, View, Controller manually but instead use scaffolds. This way you will get a working example of a redirect after create to the detail of your article and by simple change in the redirect url you can make it go to the index page.

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    
  # ...

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        # here I replaced the scaffolded `article_url(@article)` with `articles_url`
        format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: "Article was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by adding `<%= form_with scope: :article, data: { turbo: false }, url: articles_path, local: true do |f| %>` data: { turbo: false } in the new.html.erb file after this render plain: params[:article].inspect worked just fine. Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: Ok, I didn't expect the turbo to still make a XHR request when you specify `local: true`